# How to retrieve data using SQL from below table (not using PL/SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, db2

Source Table using DB2 or Oracle only SQL not Procedural Language

```
Name        Date          Amt          Reason
-----       -----        -------      ---------
A          10 Nov        200          Overdue
A          20 Nov        500          EMT
B          6 Dec         300          Overdue
B          3 Dec         100          EMT
```

Result is like unique Name among duplicates, minimum of Date, Maximum of Amt, If Overdue is there in any one of duplicates must print Overdue if not print else part.        See result table as shown below

```
Name        Date        Amt           Reason
-----      ------      -----         --------
A          10 Nov       500          Overdue
B          3 Dec        300          Overdue
```

Comment: The DATE column is not actually a DATE, it is a string. You should use date data type. H**ow would you compare the MINIMUM between two string `10 Nov` and `20 Nov`?**

Comment: Can we have a look at your current query, so we can improve it?

Comment: Are the different dates for a Name always in the same month? (Or the same year?) Can there be other Reason values than Overdue and EMT?

Comment: Date part is actually DATE but take DATA Type as your wish

Comment: here we are working on day wise files so month and year didn't changed. but some cases it will be changed so not an issue when month/year to be changed

Answer (score 0):

```
with input as (
  select 'A' name , '10 Nov' "date", 200 amt, 'Overdue' reason from dual
  union all select 'A', '20 Nov', 500, 'EMT' from dual
  union all select 'B', '6 Dec', 300, 'Overdue' from dual
  union all select 'B', '3 Dec', 100, 'EMT' from dual)
select name, min("date") "date", max(amt), 
    substr(max(decode(reason, 'Overdue', '2'||reason, '1'||reason) ), 2) reason
  from input
  group by name
```

For minimum date you can use:

```
min(to_date(decode(length("date"), 5, '0', '')||"date", 'dd MON'))
```

instead of `min("date")`